# How to enable "--squash" feature of Docker in Arch Linux?

Tags: docker, containers, archlinux

To use `--squash` feature of `Docker`, you need to enable the experimental features of the `Docker daemon`. How this can be done on `Arch Linux`?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

This is how I got it to work in ArchLinux with systemd

> /etc/docker/daemon.json

added the json blob below

```
{ 
    "experimental": true 
}
```

then restart the service

```
systemctl restart docker.service
```

For confirmation, run `docker version` and you'll see the following line in the output

```
Client: Docker Engine - Community
....
Experimental:      true
....
```

Answer (score 2):

On `Arch Linux`, you can add `--experimental=true` to the end of the `ExecStart=/usr/bin/dockerd -H fd://` line in the `/usr/lib/systemd/system/docker.service` file in order to enable the experimental feature.

Then, you need to reload and restart the `Docker daemon`:

```
systemctl daemon-reload
systemctl restart docker.service
```

Answer (score 0):

With recent docker versions neither of the methods works any more. See https://github.com/docker/cli/issues/947

As a summary, there is docker and docker cli. Both are not the same. Experimental mode must be enabled for docker cli. Thus one has to edit the file `$HOME/.docker/config.json`.